# Function to show notice when there is a new update

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a WordPress theme and I want to show a notice when there is a new update. The function that I am using is this:

```
function mytheme_new_update( $version = null ){

    $request = wp_safe_remote_get( 'https://example.com/wp-content/updates/mytheme/lib/plugin-update-checker-4.11/theme.json' );

    if ( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
        set_transient( $request, 900 );
        return false;
    }
    set_transient( $request, 86400 );


    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
    $data = json_decode( $body );

    if ( ! empty( $data ) ) {
        $current_version = $data->version;
        if( isset( $current_version ) ){
            if( 'version' == $version ){
                return $current_version;
            }
            if( ! defined('MYTHEME_VERSION') || empty( MYTHEME_VERSION ) || version_compare( $current_version, MYTHEME_VERSION, '<=' ) ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm not sure if the transient has been set properly. The function call for the notice is in my dashboard.php file and the notice appears when there's a new update but since this is a modification from another code and is a bit different, I wanted to know if it has been written correctly.